# Adobe Flex Mobile + AIR - Custom iOS Build Setting

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air, ane

I am building some Adobe Flex Mobile application using Flex 4.6.0 + AIR 3.5 only for iOS

This app involves some iOS Native Extension created also by me.

The thing is that this ANE uses some third party framework (GD.framework from Good Dynamics Technology). That framework requires GD FIPS linker to be used, and for that, i need to set some custom build settings in a *.xcconfig* file, with this content:

> FIPS_PACKAGE=$(CURRENT_ARCH).sdk LDPLUSPLUS=/Good
>   Technology/Good.platform/FIPS_module/$FIPS_PACKAGE/bin/gd_fipsld
>   LD=/Good
>   Technology/Good.platform/FIPS_module/$FIPS_PACKAGE/bin/gd_fipsld

The ANE compiles OK, but then, I add the ANE to the app, I compile the app, but when I launch the app, it crashes because the FIPS linker was not properly got set on my Flex Mobile project.

So, my question is:

Is there a way to set the above configuration on my project like somebody would do in a Xcode project?

Regards!